# Recording a Twilio call including play verb before dial verb

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

When we receive a call, we play a prompt to the caller that says something along the lines of "we may record the call for quality and training purposes".

The TWiML we send in response to the incoming call is the following.

```xml
<Response>
    <Play>http://domain.tld/may_record_call.wav</Play>
    <Dial timeout="10" callerId="5555551234" record="record-from-ringing" action="https://my_url.com/action" method="POST">
        <Client>my_user</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Our recording is created properly, but it does not include the prompt before the call is placed.

We would like proof that we properly played the prompt, and ideally it would be included in the recording we make, but the dial recording options do not seem to allow this.

[from the TWiml docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record)

> record
>
> The 'record' attribute lets you record both legs of a call within the associated  verb. When using record-from-answer, the recording will begin when a call is answered. When using record-from ringing, the recording will begin when the ringing starts. In both cases, a RecordingUrl parameter will be sent to the 'action' URL on the associated  verb. You must set an 'action' URL to receive the RecordingUrl.

I can't add the play after the dial, because when the call is answered, further verbs after the dial are not executed.

My question is how do I record my call recording warning as part of my call recording? Is there another hidden record value that can be used? Is there a way to get the dial to start, but play the prompt to caller?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an outbound call, in your API request include the optional POST parameter `Record=true`.  This will record the entirety of a phone call, including the `<Play>` and `<Dial>` tags.  The `RecordingUrl` will be sent to the `StatusCallback` URL.  You will then probably want to remove the `record` parameter from `<Dial>` tag, or you'll end up with two recordings of the conversation.

You can read more about recording calls this way in the [API documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional).

You can learn more about the various ways Twilio records calls in [Twilio Skills Training](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/call-recording/1.html#ways-twilio-records-calls).

Comment: My original question mentioned it was an inbound call, so unfortunately this flag does not apply.

However, the skills training link did point out the record verb. I will have to try using that instead of the record noun on the dial verb.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to have 2 Twilio numbers. Original number and a second one which records and redirects calls when call is answered.

redirect.xml

```
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="10" record="record-from-ringing">
        <Number>+164666XXXX</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The first number Voice URL points to redirect.xml 
The second Twilio (original) number 164666XXXX Voice URL is configured using recording.xml

```
<Response>
    <Play>http://domain.tld/may_record_call.wav</Play>
    <Dial timeout="10" action="https://my_url.com/action" method="POST">
        <Client>my_user</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The recording will appear under first number. This involves extra cost but is a workaround which I successfully tested.

Comment: Interesting idea. The problem I see with that is I would lose the original caller id information when calling my second number. From the second number the caller id would be `1415319XXXX`. For our system knowing who is calling is extremely important.